# SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide (Exam 310-065) example from chapter 10 Development "-classpath"

Tags: java

Given the default classpath:

```
/foo
```

And this directory structure:

```
foo
  |
 test
    |
   xcom
     |--A.class
     |--B.java
```

And these two files:

```
package xcom;
public class A { }

package xcom;
public class B extends A { }
```

Why it doesn't work?

```
javac -cp test xcom\A.java
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the `-classpath` argument to the `javac` compiler tells the compiler where to find already compiled files that your code uses, not where to find the files you want to compile. [Use the `-sourcepath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options) argument instead.

And in the future, when you post a question about something that "doesn't work" please include the exact information about what errors you get, what the tool outputs, etc. - to enable people to more easily help you.

Answer (score 0):

Because `A.java` is not present in the `foo/test/xcom` folder?

Answer (score 0):

The file A.java doesn't exist. You have the compiled class file instead (file A.class)

With the folders and files you have posted, you only could compile B.java:

```
javac -cp test xcom\B.java
```